# Cómo cambiar el color entre 3 opciones en BATCH

Tags: batch

Estoy aprendiendo BATCH; una tarea que tengo que hacer es un programa que me permita elegir entre 3 colores y que se cambie el color de fondo y letra. Tengo este código hecho pero no sé avanzar más; posiblemente haya alguna burrada (no podemos usar condicionales).

```
@echo off
title programa Cambiodecolor
set/p pregunta1=Quieres cambiar el color?
set/p pregunta2=De verdad que lo quieres cambiar?
echo Al cambiar el color o al cerrar este programas aceptas poner a Jonatan Diego Cobo un 10 en este trimestre.
echo 
echo color 4A
echo color 4B
echo color 4C
set/p PA= ¿Quieres cambiar a este color?
set/p PA1= ¿Quieres cambiar a este color?
set/p PA2=  ¿Quieres cambiar a este color?
@echo
pause
exit
```

Comment: El comando color es sin echo delante. Color 4A (fondo rojo, letra verde),: color 4C (rojo/rojo claro). No puedes poner dos números iguales porque no hace nada. Para las opciones puedes usar choice /c 123, donde 123 es las teclas que debe aceptar, 1 o 2 o 3. P:ara saber cial eligió preguntas por el ERRORLEVEL : if errorlevel 3 goto opcion3. Los if del errorlevel deben estar de mayor a menor. Prueba y si te sirve de algo puedes poner como respuesta. Esto es puro batch.

Comment: En el choice puedes poner la pregunta: choice /c:YN /M Quieres cambiar el color

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto(debes tener BATBOX)

```
@Echo off  
title Programa cambio de color  
color 0f  
:Preg1  
color 0f  
set /p pregunta1=quieres cambiar el color?  

if %pregunta1%==si (goto lp) else (goto preg1)  
:lp  
cls  
set /p pregunta2=De verdad que lo quieres cambiar?  
if %pregunta2%==si (goto 1)  
if %pregunta2%==no (exit /b)  
goto lp  
:1  
color 0f  
cls  
Echo.  
Echo                                               -DISFRUTALO AMIGO-  
Echo.  

batbox /d "Al cambiar el color o al cerrar este programa aceptas poner a " /c 0xc0 /d "Jonatan Diego Cobo" /c 0x0f /d " un " /c 0xa0 /d "10" /c 0x0f /d " en este trimestre."  
echo.  
echo.  
echo.  
batbox /c 0x4a /d "color 4A"  
echo.  
batbox /c 0x4b /d "color 4B"  
echo.  
batbox /c 0x4c /d "color 4C"  
echo.  
echo.  
batbox /c 0x4a /d "Quieres cambiar a este color?"&set /p pa=  
if %pa%==si (set _c=4a&goto fin)  
Echo.  
Echo.  
batbox /c 0x4b /d "Quieres cambiar a este color?"&set /p pa1=  
if %pa1%==si (set _c=4b&goto fin)  
Echo.  
Echo.  
batbox /c 0x4c /d "Quieres cambiar a este color?"&set /p pa2=  
if %pa2%==si (set _c=4c&goto fin) else (goto el)  
Echo.  
Echo.  
exit /b  
:el  
color 0f  
cls  
Echo.  
Echo.  
batbox /c 0xc0 /d "VAMOS! TIENES QUE ELEJIR ALGO"  
pause>nul  
goto 1  
:fin  
color %_c%  
cls  
Echo.  
Echo NO SE SI QUERIAS ESTO PERO ESPERO ESTAR RONDANDO LO QUE QUERIAS.  
set /p z=^>  
if %z%==si (Echo ME ALEGRO&pause>nul&Exit /b)  
if %z%==Si (Echo ME ALEGRO&pause>nul&Exit /b)  
if %z%==sI (Echo ME ALEGRO&pause>nul&Exit /b)  
if %z%==SI (Echo ME ALEGRO&pause>nul&Exit /b)  
if %z%==no (Echo PERDONAME :[ &pause>nul&Exit /b)  
if %z%==No (Echo PERDONAME :[ &pause>nul&Exit /b)  
if %z%==NO (Echo PERDONAME :[ &pause>nul&Exit /b)  
if %z%==nO (Echo PERDONAME :[ &pause>nul&Exit /b)  
goto fin
```

Comment: No agregues dos respuestas, edita la que ya tienes y agrega lo que te falte por aclarar

Comment: Perdón quería explicar en uno y pasar el código en otro así no copia lo que no es.

Answer (score -2):

Lo que puedes hacer es descargar un archivo auxiliar llamado Batbox

Te diré como cambiar el color a continuación y te explicare para que sirve cada parte

Una vez descargado Este sería el codigo:

```
@Echo off

Title CAMBIADOR DE COLOR

:Menu  
cls  
Set /p Texto=Escribe el texto^>  
set /p Color=Escribe el color^>  
::Esto transforma lo que escribiste en la variable color a dos numeros que batbox interpretara como color.  
if %color%==negro (set _color=0f)  
if %color%==azul (set _primc=1f)  
if %color%==verde (set _primc=2f)  
if %color%==aguamarina (set _primc=3f)  
if %color%==rojo (set _primc=4f)  
if %color%==purpura (set _primc=5f)  
if %color%==amarillo (set _primc=6f)  
if %color%==blanco (set _primc=70)  
if %color%==gris (set _primc=8f)  

::Aqui lo muestra /g sirve para la posición en este caso X:10 y:5 /c es el color  


Batbox /g 10 5 /c 0x%_primc% /d "%texto%"  
pause>nul  
goto menu
```

::Espero que entiendas. En caso contrario puedes buscar más sobre batbox y otros programas auxiliares ;) y puedes hacer lo que te plazca escribir lo que sea con colores combinados.